# How to host ASP.NET Core 3.1 as a virtual service account?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebAPI app with `UseWindowsService` feature and I can host as this as window service.

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseHttpSys();
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.Configure<HttpSysOptions>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UrlPrefixes.Add(context.Configuration["HttpSysOptions:UrlPrefix"]);
                    });
                });

                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            //host as window service
            .UseWindowsService()
```

Now I can use below command to install it as window service,

```
 SC create MyService displayname= "My Service" binpath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Demo\Demo.exe" start= auto
```

and this running as `local system`. perfect!

Now I want to run this as a virtual service account `NT Service\Demo` rather than `local system`, how I can this? Please suggest!

Comment: I removed those confusing lines. Thanks!

Comment: `sc config "MyService" obj= "NT Service\Demo" password= "sw0rdF1sh"`

Comment: Thanks, but we don't have pre created virtual service account, also we cant set the password.

Comment: Use `obj= "NT SERVICE\MyService"` to specify a virtual service account for the service. The name must match the service name, and no password is required. This is really just a question of how to use `sc.exe` and has nothing to do with .NET as such.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert. I am able to host it.